# How to rename newly columns that are created by operation on GroupedDataset in Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

How can I rename the columns of `count` operation without converting result to DataFrame?

```
case class LogRow(id: String, location: String, time: Long)
case class KeyValue(key: (String, String), value: Long)

val log = LogRow("1", "a", 1) :: LogRow("1", "a", 2) :: LogRow("1", "b", 3) :: LogRow("1", "a", 4) :: LogRow("1", "b", 5) :: LogRow("1", "b", 6) :: LogRow("1", "c", 7) :: LogRow("2", "a", 1) :: LogRow("2", "b", 2) :: LogRow("2", "b", 3) :: LogRow("2", "a", 4) :: LogRow("2", "a", 5) :: LogRow("2", "a", 6) :: LogRow("2", "c", 7) :: Nil
log.toDS().groupBy(l => {
  (l.id, l.location)
}).count().toDF().toDF("key", "value").as[KeyValue].show

+-----+-----+
|  key|value|
+-----+-----+
|[1,a]|    3|
|[1,b]|    3|
|[1,c]|    1|
|[2,a]|    4|
|[2,b]|    2|
|[2,c]|    1|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: what do u mean by change the columns? rename?

Comment: Excuse me, yes rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map it to the required type directly:

```
log.toDS.groupBy(l => {
  (l.id, l.location)
}).count.as[KeyValue]
```